# Splitting date and time from text in R in new column

Tags: r

my data is in the format given

How to take date and time in column 1 and rest of the text in column 2? Please help

```
10/05/2017, 17:50 - Messages you send to this group are now secured with end-to-end encryption. Tap for more info.


10/05/2017, 17:35 - â€ª+91 85869 81933â€¬ created group â€œShubhaaram Zone Northâ€

10/05/2017, 17:50 - Sang added you

10/05/2017, 17:51 - Sang added Soumit Deb

10/05/2017, 17:51 - Sang added â€ª+91 98180 09003â€¬

10/05/2017, 17:53 - Sang added Astha Mckinsey

10/05/2017, 17:55 - Sang added â€ª+91 96505 77422â€¬

10/05/2017, 17:58 - Sang added â€ª+91 99106 61584â€¬

10/05/2017, 17:58 - Sang added â€ª+91 96542 00700â€¬

10/05/2017, 17:59 - Sang added â€ª+91 88722 03311â€¬

10/05/2017, 18:01 - Sang added Alok
```

Comment: See `?strsplit` for one method.

Answer (score 0):

Example data.frame:

```
df<- data.frame(col1= c("10/05/2017, 17:50 - Sang added you","10/05/2017, 17:51 - Sang added Soumit Deb"))
```

Using strsplit:

```
df$datetime<-unlist(lapply(as.character(df$col1), function(x) strsplit(x, split="-")[[1]][1]))
df$rest<-unlist(lapply(as.character(df$col1), function(x) strsplit(x, split="-")[[1]][2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use stringr's `str_split_fixed` function, assuming df is :

```
df <- data.frame(col = c("10/05/2017, 17:50 - Messages you send to this group are now secured with end-to-end encryption. Tap for more info.",
                         "10/05/2017, 17:35 - â€ª+91 85869 81933â€¬ created group â€œShubhaaram Zone Northâ€",
                         "10/05/2017, 17:50 - Sang added you",
                         "10/05/2017, 17:51 - Sang added Soumit Deb",
                         "10/05/2017, 17:51 - Sang added â€ª+91 98180 09003â€¬",
                         "10/05/2017, 17:53 - Sang added Astha Mckinsey",
                         "10/05/2017, 17:55 - Sang added â€ª+91 96505 77422â€¬",
                         "10/05/2017, 17:58 - Sang added â€ª+91 99106 61584â€¬",
                         "10/05/2017, 17:58 - Sang added â€ª+91 96542 00700â€¬",
                         "10/05/2017, 17:59 - Sang added â€ª+91 88722 03311â€¬",
                         "10/05/2017, 18:01 - Sang added Alok"))
```

**Solution**:
Here df1 is your final solution

```
df1 <- setNames(data.frame(stringr::str_split_fixed(df$col,"-",n=2)),c("Datetime","Message"))
```